# Data in Array is Incomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-promise

Data in Array is Incomplete
[image]
[image]

## it get only last item.
I need to get all item.
how to fix this?

## source code

```
  let GetProvinceWithSumCovid19 = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < GetProvince.length; index++) {
    GetProvinceWithSumCovid19 = dataFromAmCharts.filter(x => x.name.indexOf(GetProvince[index].providersEN) > -1);
    GetProvinceWithSumCovid19.push({
      value: GetProvince[index].sumCovid19
    })
  }; 
  console.log(GetProvinceWithSumCovid19);
```

Comment: We can not copy and paste code from an image

Comment: because you overwrite your variable on every iteration

Comment: ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - *copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.*

Comment: i should declare new variable right?

Comment: It would help if you could give us the data set you're trying to work with, or a sample or subset of it at least. It appears as though you're trying to filter the data and create objects, but since you're doing it in a for loop (the filter function will replace existing data since you're assigning, not pushing) you will only get the last bit of data.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in the for loop overwrites `GetProvinceWithSumCovid19`

Comment: thank for answer , i should to delete GetProvinceWithSumCovid19 right ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning to **GetProvinceWithSumCovid19** variable, push to it.

```
var GetProvinceWithSumCovid19 = [];
for (let index = 0; index < GetProvince.length; index++) {
    GetProvinceWithSumCovid19.push(dataFromAmCharts.filter(x => x.name.indexOf(GetProvince[index].providersEN) > -1));
    GetProvinceWithSumCovid19.push({
        value: GetProvince[index].sumCovid19
    })
};
console.log(GetProvinceWithSumCovid19);
```

The output structure would be like:

`[[{id:, name:},{id:, name:}], {value:2}, [{id:, name:}], {value:1}]`

But I really doubt whether this is the structure you want. The required output structure is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of information to go off of here, but looking at the second image of the output, I believe you're trying to do something like this:

```js
const getProvinceWithSumCovid19 = GetProvince.map((item, index) => {
    return {
        [dataFromAmCharts.filter(x => x.name.indexOf(GetProvince[index].providersEN) > -1)], 
        value: GetProvince[index].sumCovid19 
    }
});

console.log(getProvinceWithSumCovid19);
```

Comment: I could simplify it further if I could clearly understand your intent

Comment: Do you expect to find more than one value in the `filter()` results? If not, I believe you can use `find()` instead